# Install4j - how to set default value for "Can be executed multiple times" attribute?

Tags: java, install4j

I'm trying to write a custom `Action` to use within **install4j**. I've studied the [documentation on extending install4j](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/). In that light, I'm extending `AbstractInstallOrUninstallAction` and have added a proper bean info by extending `ActionBeanInfo`. All have been going well until I decided to polish things a little and set some of the default attributes of my custom action like *Default Action Elevation Type*.

I noticed that these properties are not inherited by my action and I have to use proper setters from within bean info for that matter, e.g., `setDefaultActionElevationType(ActionElevationType.ELEVATE, true)`.

I can find most of these attributes using provided setters except for **Can be executed multiple times** which is internally referred to as `multiExec` by install4j.

Does anyone know a workaround so that this could also be set using the action's bean info or action itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In install4j 5.x this is not possible. In install4j 6.0 the method `com.install4j.api.beaninfo.ActionBeanInfo#setDefaultMultiExec` will be added.